# If $AB$ is a subgroup, then $[A,B] \unlhd AB$. Is this true/known/used?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $A, B \le G$ such that $AB = BA$ (i.e. $AB$ is a subgroup), then $[A,B]$ is normal in $AB$.

Proof: For $a' \in A, b' \in B$ we have
$$
 [a,b]^{a'} = [aa', b][a',b]^{-1} \in [A,B]
$$
and
$$
 [a,b]^{b'} = ([b,a]^{-1})^{b'} = ([b,a]^{b'})^{-1} = ([bb', a][b',a]^{-1})^{-1} \in [A,B]. \quad \square
$$

Is this right? This seems to be a nice little fact, but it is nowhere mentioned; so I ask if I have maybe overlooked something?

Comment: It is well-known.You may find it as an easy lemma in some classic group theory textbooks.

Comment: The more general result is $[A,B] \unlhd \langle A,B \rangle$ for any subgroup $A,B \le G$. It is prove, for example, in Thm 2.1 Chapter 2 of Gorenstein's Finite Groups.

Comment: (continuing Holt's comment): you hypothesis says that $\langle A,B\rangle$=(the smallest subgroup containing $A$ and $B$) = $AB$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your comments! Good to know that $A, B \le N_G([A,B])$ is well-known.